# Further matching after pd.merge using another key

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge, nan

I have merged 2 DataFrame (df1, df2) and there are some unmatches (NaN) using `Key1`. For some of those, there is further possible match by using `key2` (but only for NaNs).

What is the best approach to *only* match further match the NaNs?

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = {'key1': ['abc','efg', 'xyz', 'sdf'],
         'key2' : ['123','345','567','900'],
         'emotion' : ['happy','busy','funny','excited']
        }

data2 = {'key1': ['abc','efg', 'aaa', 'sdf'],
         'key2' : ['123','345','567','600'],
         'why' : ['holiday','school','monkey','happy']
        }

df1= pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2= pd.DataFrame(data2)

df1.merge(df2, how = 'left',on = 'key1')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way do it side by side then `fillna`

```
s1 = df1.reset_index().merge(df2,on='key1',how='left').set_index('index')
s2 = df1.reset_index().merge(df2,on='key2',how='left').set_index('index')
out = s1.fillna(s2)
out
Out[30]: 
      key1 key2_x  emotion key2_y      why
index                                     
0      abc    123    happy    123  holiday
1      efg    345     busy    345   school
2      xyz    567    funny    NaN   monkey
3      sdf    900  excited    600    happy
```